# OSX: Cannot unlock etc/paths file

Tags: macos, terminal, file-unlocking

I would like to edit /etc/paths file in my Mac computer.

I am a newbie and I am trying to unlock the file. I tried in Terminal to do :

```
etc tomasteicher$ sudo chflags nouchg /etc/paths
etc tomasteicher$ open -e /etc/paths
```

Almost all tutorials I have found recommend this solution.
The second command open file in TextEdit but the file is still locked.

Has anybody a tip, how can I unlock file, or why this solution does not work for this file?

Answer (score 9):

It's not actually locked, you just don't have permission to edit it. Instead, use a command-line text editor like `vim` to edit this file.

Use `sudo vim /etc/paths` to edit the file from the command line. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to start typing (navigate with arrow keys), press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when done. Then type `:wq` and <kbd>Return</kbd>

---

Note that in many situations, it's easier to add executable paths to a user-specific configuration file, like `~/.bash_profile`, or add new files in `/etc/paths.d` with additional paths.

Comment: Unhelpful. I continue to get `Permission denied` errors when editing either `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d/macports`, with `sudo`, after running `chflags nouch <path>`.